# How to send a command to RS232 Serial Port PBX Harris 20-20 using pySerial?

Tags: python, pyserial, pbx

There is a need for automatic time adjustment PBX Harris 20-20.
In order to synchronize the time necessary via RS232 connect to the PBX and enter a certain command.
To automate the process, it was decided to use pySerial.
In order to connect to the PBX it is necessary to send to the port the command ETX (end of text).
In order this to work in the program, you must send to the port '\x03'.
The sample of code is shown below:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM12', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, xonxoff=1)
ser.write(chr(3))
```

The output should look something like this:

```
<ETX> [len=2]
[len=0]
<LF><LF>*** NO DEFAULT AVAILABLE *** [len=30]
<LF> [len=1]
<LF>Username ...?
```

But the output is only this:

```
<ETX>
```

The command ETX is sent to the PBX, but there was no response.
How to get a response from the PBX?

Comment: It may sounds silly but do you actually perform a read operation using ser.read method ?

Comment: Are you executing `ser.readline()`? If so, it will only read until it decects a newline character. Try executing it several times, or execute `ser.read(100)` to read 100 bytes (if possible).

Comment: I do. `ser.read(100)` exactly, but it doesn't helps. The programm just hang off, untill I installed parameter `timeout` to 1.I think that the PBX waits for a certain command or character.

Comment: Your post seems to suggest all you have to send is the '\x03' character. It is likely that you will also need to send a line termination character ('\n') (or any of the typical line termination characters like '\r', '\r\n').